# Spring Boot test: get @Autowired to work without using `SpringRunner`

Tags: spring-boot, pact

I am writing a ***pact provider test*** in a Spring Boot application. The controller has two dependencies for which one of them should be mocked and the other one shouldn't.

Since I am writing the [pact test](https://docs.pact.io/) (which I'm new to it), I have to use `@RunWith(RestPactRunner.class)` on top of my test class.

in my test class I use `@Autowired` on the dependency that I don't want to mock but since I can't use `SpringRunner` my test doesn't know how to find the dependency and leaves it as `null`.

Here is the ***pact*** provider test:

```java
@RunWith(RestPactRunner.class)
@Provider("provider_name")
@PactFolder("target/pacts")
public class SampleProviderTest {
    private MetadataController metadataController;

    @Mock
    private BlockService blockService; // dependency #1: to be mocked

    @Autowired
    private BlockMapper blockMapper; // dependency #2: to be injected

    @TestTarget
    public final MockMvcTarget target = new MockMvcTarget();

    @Before
    public void before() {
        initMocks(this);
        metadataController = new MetadataController(blockService, blockMapper);
        target.setControllers(metadataController);
    }


    /*
    * you can ignore the rest of this test class
    */


    @State("block info")
    public void blockInfo() {
        Block requestedBlock = new Block();
        when(blockService.getBlockInfo(123L, 12345L, "S1", "B1")).thenReturn(requestedBlock);
    }

}
```

**Question**:
    - how do I get this test to pick up the right implementation for the dependency #2 above (`blockMapper`)? right now it remains null

Comment: Try using @InjectMocks instead of Autowired

Comment: You cannot. You cannot have framework features without using the framework. So you either need to write some extension to pact (if that is possible) or manually create an `ApplicationContext` and auto wire the beans, or create the service yourself (including all the dependencies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after struggling with how to find the BlockMapper (actual implementation) without using `@Autowired` I finally used `mapstruct`'s `Mapper` class to find the implementation in my test, that's how I did it:

```java
@RunWith(RestPactRunner.class)
@Provider("provider_name")
@PactFolder("target/pacts")
public class SampleProviderTest {
    private MetadataController metadataController;

    @Mock
    private BlockService blockService; // dependency #1: to be mocked

    @TestTarget
    public final MockMvcTarget target = new MockMvcTarget();

    @Before
    public void before() {
        initMocks(this);

        // dependency #2: to be injected
        BlockMapper blockMapper = Mappers.getMapper(BlockMapper.class);

        metadataController = new MetadataController(blockService, blockMapper);
        target.setControllers(metadataController);
    }


    /*
    * removed the remainder...
    */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the annotation `@RunWith(SpringRestPactRunner.class)` instead of `@RunWith(RestPactRunner.class)` .Using `SpringRestPactRunner` instead of PactRunner as the Junit’s runner allows us to use spring test annotations.

```
@RunWith(SpringRestPactRunner.class)
@Provider("provider_name")
@PactFolder("target/pacts")
public class SampleProviderTest {
    private MetadataController metadataController;
```

You could also try using the annotation `@WebMvcTest(MetadataController.class)` along with the springrestpackrunner as for testing your controller all you need are web related components in the application context and the other layer beans could be mocked.

Comment: I saw usage of `SpringRestPactRunner` in some code samples and my IDE couldn't find it and I assumed it is no longer supported in the most recent version of the library, can you tell me how to import it (or where to import it from)?

Answer (score 0):

I used `@RunWith(SpringRestPactRunner.class)` but it errors: Connect to localhost:8080, anyone know this?